# (The attribute image.itemtype has an invalid value.)

Tags: html, schema.org, structured-data

```
<img itemprop="image" alt="Picture." src="http://www.websitename.com/img/picture.jpg"/>
```

Here's my code. (Microdata). It gives me a warning on Googles Structured data testing tool.